# Smallest, specific RNA-binding protein - w/ sequence?

Tags: rna, protein-binding

I'm looking to synthetically fuse an RNA-binding protein onto another protein, inside a viral vector which has a size-limit. I've considered some options, but I'm wondering what StackExchange will say. What is the smallest protein known that binds to a specific sequence of RNA, and what is that sequence?

Comment: This is Stack Exchange Biology. StackOverflow is the computing site.

Comment: @David - while in itself obviously true, I don't understand your comment in this context?

Comment: He has now corrected an initial mistake / typo.